# Gitlab Installation on Suse SLES 11 - Not able to login to Gitlab GUI

Tags: gitlab, suse

After the complete successful installation I am still not able to login to the gitlab GUI. It keeps on throwing "**invalid email or password**"

The following are the output for the recommended solutions suggested by others:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAI                                                                             LS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.1 ? ... OK (1.7.1)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects
Projects have satellites? ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.12)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

and

```
bundle exec rake db:seed_fu RAILS_ENV=production                                                                             
== Seed from /home/git/gitlab/db/fixtures/production/001_admin.rb
INFO: Sidekiq client using redis://localhost:6379 with options {:namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}

Administrator account created:

login.........admin@local.host
password......5iveL!fe
```

Now the issue is I fire the url and I get the login screen but unfortunately when I enter the credentials generated above I keep getting the error about invalid email/password.

What would you suggest to get past that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a recurring issue, followed in[issue 7226](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7226).

Some of the workarounds suggested are:

> The command `gitlab-rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production` solves the problem.
>
> It is impossible to login as `root` but it is possible to sign in new standard users and they log in just fine; when this happens the command `gitlab-rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production` fixes root login (possibly erasing everything else in the db, I guess).

The [OP KronnorK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716872/kronnork) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263131/gitlab-installation-on-suse-sles-11-not-able-to-login-to-gitlab-gui/32264319#comment52761605_32264319) it was a setting issue (AD settings had wrong user and password), and once fixed, the setup command restored the system.

Comment: Hi VonC, gitlab-rake is missing from the gitlab binaries.... Am I missing something here ? Is there another way to resolve this? Can I install the gitlab-rake binary ? Please help!

Comment: ~/gitlab> gitlab-rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
If 'gitlab-rake' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found gitlab-rake
-bash: gitlab-rake: command not found

Comment: @KronnorK then this could help: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/525

Comment: i tried the following:   bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production

Administrator account created:

login.........admin@local.host
password......5iveL!fe     I still get the invalid credentials errors ... I tried root/admin/admin@local.host and the password combination but still it is failing

Comment: @KronnorK did you restart everything after the `gitlab-rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: @Now I get 500

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

Comment: @KronnorK maybe the logs on the server side can have more clues as to what trigger this "internal error" 500.

Comment: Finally made it working with AD... my settings were wrong ... Thanks so much for the pointers.. I need to document this now... as I had a lot of source code modifications to make it work on Suse

Comment: my AD settings had wrong user and password... after that I did run the setup command and got it fixed